# How to plot a bisector line on Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a Scatter chart and I need to trace the bisector line on it. I'm wondering if there is a automated way on Plotly to generate that, or a simplified way to calculate the equation in python to generate the list of values and trace the line.

My code:

```py
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = eixo_x, # My list of values for 'x'
    y = eixo_y, # My list of values for 'y'
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict(color = 'rgb(0, 176, 240)')
)

dados = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Unitários Observados | Unitários Estimados',
    autosize = False,
    width = 1000,
    height = 500,
    xaxis = dict(
        showgrid = True),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        showgrid = True
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data = dados, layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

My Plot:

[image]

Now I need to plot a line on diagonal, the bisector.

**EDIT**

There are a few questions about bisector, but not for Plotly.

**EDIT 2**

> In geometry, bisection is the division of something into two equal or congruent parts, usually by a line, which is then called a bisector. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection)

Example:

[image]

Comment: By bisector, do you mean best fit line through all of the datapoints?

Comment: I've added a few more details on my question. Hope that can help.

Comment: So a line from the bottom left corner to the top right corner?

Comment: As you have said yourself, bisection works on two existing lines, some place with an angle. I can see no angle on your data. Only points.

Comment: The angle should be calculated based on 'x' and 'y' axis values with the purpose of divide my points on plot in two sections.

Comment: The 'lines' in this case are the x/y axis @alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use an equation or an automated function from Plotly but the following code solved my problem temporarily:

I've setted the line limits for x and y getting the min and max from each list:

```py
# Trace 2
line_x = [min(eixo_x), max(eixo_x)]
line_y = [min(eixo_y), max(eixo_y)]
```

And added a second trace for it:

```py
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x = line_x,
    y = line_y,
    mode = 'lines',
    marker = dict(color = 'rgb(127, 127, 127)'),
    line = dict(dash = 'dash')
)
```

Result:

[image]